# Branch coverage with JaCoCo, Emma from IntelliJ

Tags: unit-testing, junit, intellij-idea, code-coverage

I am trying to measure branch coverage of unit tests for a large Grails application. I am using JaCoCo, Emma and IDEA to collect the metrics from inside IntelliJ, I am getting the following:

- JaCoCo (no metrics are shown even for line coverage)
- Emma (produces method and line coverage)
- IDEA (produces class, method and line coverage)

I am mostly interested in JaCoCo as it should give me Branch Coverage by default. Could someone point me to some tips on how to troubleshoot this?

Comment: I have a similar question, but mine is about generating branch coverage data by IDEA coverage runner. Have you figured out a solution to do that?

Comment: @yaobin: _The IntelliJ IDEA coverage engine currently supports Class, Method and Line coverage. There is no Branch/Block coverage yet._ (Ref: https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/TCD9/IntelliJ+IDEA)

Comment: Actually, there is visual indicator for branch-coverage within left gutter on the editor.
"The yellow mark indicates that the line was executed partially, for example, if only one condition from the if statement was checked"
(ref: http://blog.jetbrains.com/idea/2006/07/code-coverage/)

Answer (score 16):

Actually IntelliJ code coverage tool supports branch coverage though it does not show the results on the summary. Check this article to see how it can be configured and how you can check your branch coverage: https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/IDEADEV/IDEA+Coverage+Runner
The key is to use Tracing instead of Sampling.

Comment: Note that Tracing is only available with Intellij as the runner.